# POSTGRESQL GROUP BY QUERY

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

```sql
SELECT
    concat(
        EXTRACT(
            YEAR
            FROM
                "BEAUFTRAGUNG_DATUM"
        ),
        '-',
        TO_CHAR(
            EXTRACT(
                MONTH
                FROM
                    "BEAUFTRAGUNG_DATUM"
            ),
            'fm00'
        )
    ) AS "DATUM",
    CASE
        WHEN (
            "STATUS" in (
                '....', '...'
            )
        ) THEN 'OTHER'
        WHEN ("STATUS" = 'BESTELLT') THEN 'BESTELLT'
        WHEN ("STATUS" = 'VOR_PRODUKTION') THEN 'VOR_PRODUKTION'
    END AS "MODIFIED_STATUS",
    COUNT(*) AS "ANZAHL"
FROM
    PUBLIC."TXS"
WHERE
    "FLAG_POS" = '1'
GROUP BY
    "DATUM",
    "MODIFIED_STATUS"
ORDER BY
    "DATUM" ASC
```

This is what I have.

And I want it like this

```
DATUM       OTHER     BESTELLT       VOR_PRODUKTION
2021-11     47        87             366
2022-01     1         0              0
2022-02     82        73             356
```

So that I have unique dates.
Thanks in advance.
I tried some solutions with "JOINS" but none of them worked.
I hope that you have any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

This query should be able to get the desired result with the given information:

```sql
SELECT
    txs.DATUM,
    COALESCE(other.sum, 0) AS other,
    COALESCE(bestellt.sum, 0) AS bestellt,
    COALESCE(vor_produktion.sum, 0) AS vor_produktion
FROM
    PUBLIC."TXS" txs
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tsx2.DATUM, SUM(tsx2.ANZAHL) AS sum FROM PUBLIC."TXS" tsx2 WHERE tsx2.MODIFIED_STATUS = 'OTHER' GROUP BY tsx2.DATUM) other ON other.DATUM = txs.DATUM
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tsx2.DATUM, SUM(tsx2.ANZAHL) AS sum FROM PUBLIC."TXS" tsx2 WHERE tsx2.MODIFIED_STATUS = 'BESTELLT' GROUP BY tsx2.DATUM) bestellt ON bestellt.DATUM = txs.DATUM
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tsx2.DATUM, SUM(tsx2.ANZAHL) AS sum FROM PUBLIC."TXS" tsx2 WHERE tsx2.MODIFIED_STATUS = 'VOR_PRODUKTION' GROUP BY tsx2.DATUM) vor_produktion ON vor_produktion.DATUM = txs.DATUM
GROUP BY txs.DATUM, other.sum, bestellt.sum, vor_produktion.sum
```

Here we left join the 3 columns with a subquery and replaces `<null>` values with `0`